# Sending/receiving global notifications in Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: c#, notifications, windows-phone, windows-phone-8.1

For a while I've been trying to think of ways to achieve a simple task: I have two background tasks in my app, and I want one to notify the other about certain changes (only one-way communication required), but for the life of me I can't figure out any way that works. These are the methods I found from the internet, but all of them have issues:

1. I thought I could create a simple text file in the local folder of the app and put the notifications there. The listening process could somehow subscribe to that file and be notified of any changes in its content. This was achievable previously with the *FileSystemWatcher* class, but it was removed from Windows 8 onwards.
2. Then I found another API for implementing the above method, namely the *QueryOptions* class. But it turned that while it's available in Store apps, it's not supported on Windows Phone.
3. I thought about using push notifications, but they're all linked to a web service. As of yet I can't figure out any way to use them to send and receive notifications locally without a web server.

Is there any way to go about doing this? It seems like a very straightforward task but it's turning out to be impossible to achieve. Is there any other API on Windows Phone that allows a process to be notified when the contents of a file are changed? Or is there any way I can work around with push notifications and achieve this? I also read in places that named pipes and sockets are often used to achieve this kind of functionality on other platforms, is there any way to apply this here?

Short of polling the text file for changes every half a second or so (which would be highly inefficient and introduce lag which is something my app can't tolerate), I can't figure out any other way to achieve this task.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a general-purpose IPC mechanism across two or more processes *in the same app*, you can look into [this sample](http://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2013/03/27/using-named-events-to-coordinate-foreground-apps-and-background-agents/) which wraps Win32 IPC primitives.

There is no way to "wake up" a process (or start a background task) when a file changes. So this only works if the processes will be running at the same time (if they're not running at the same time, you can use some other sort of signaling mechanism, such as a placeholder file on disk).

There is also no way to signal across two different apps; you have to round-trip via the network for that (eg, one app pings a server that relays it to the other app).

Comment: Thanks, I came across this sample on code.msdn but was having trouble understanding how it works. Anyway, this explanation implies that I should have a different NamedEvent for every kind of message I want to send/receive, is that feasible if I have, say 5-6 different named events? Because right now I've implemented a somewhat dodgy communication channel using TCP stream sockets which sometimes randomly throws exceptions for no apparent reason. Would it be better to implement IPC this way?

Comment: Actually it seems this will be rather tricky to implement in a WP8.1 RunTime app. The WaitCallBack class is only available in Silverlight, and the [ThreadPool class used in the link you gave](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Threading.ThreadPool%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is different from [the one available in WP8.1](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.system.threading.threadpool.aspx).

Comment: The `WaitCallback` and `ThreadPool` types are just parts of the sample; they are not needed in a real app (there are also trivial replacements in WinRT). You don't necessarily need different events for each message - you could for example write the message to disk (under a shared mutex) and then signal a single "new message available" event; it's up to you how you implement it.

Comment: Right, so even though I got what I wanted working in a separate test project, when I merge it with my main app it's giving a strange issue: I'm having to change the target architecture from neutral to ARM in order to compile the lpcWrapper class, but for some reason that causes the background audio task to fail i.e. it never registers correctly and the task.OnCanceled event fires, even though it works fine with the target architecture on neutral. Any idea?

Comment: In the **Configuration Manager** dialog (accessible from the drop-down next to "Debug" in the toolbar), make sure that the C++ project and the .NET project always match in terms of architecture.

Comment: Got it working. It's a peculiar phenomenon: if you create a NamedEvent variable in the main background task class, the task will always fail to start. If you simply initialize and use a variable inside a function everything works. I'm guessing that while the task is starting, the audio and NamedEvent class both try to access some exclusive resource or service so it doesn't work. Do it a while later and it runs fine. Thanks for your help.